# Failed to scrape the link to the next page using xpath in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, xpath, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape the link to the next page from this [webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping). I know how to scrape that using css selector. However, things go wrong when I attempt to parse the same using xpath. [This](https://pastebin.com/higxavw4) is what I get instead of the next page link.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
let url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping";
 
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    
    await page.goto(url,{waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    let nextPageLink = await page.$x("//a[@rel='next']", item => item.getAttribute("href"));
    // let nextPageLink = await page.$eval("a[rel='next']", elm => elm.href);
    console.log("next page:",nextPageLink);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

> How can I scrape the link to the next page using xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`page.$x(expression)`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagexexpression) returns an array of element handles. You need either destructuring or index acces to get the first element from the array.
2. To get a DOM element property from this element handle, you need either evaluating with element handle parameter or element handle API.

```js
const [nextPageLink] = await page.$x("//a[@rel='next']");
const nextPageURL = await nextPageLink.evaluate(link => link.href);
```

Or:

```js
const [nextPageLink] = await page.$x("//a[@rel='next']");
const nextPageURL = await (await nextPageURL.getProperty('href')).jsonValue();
```